# How to send Mails using NGINX

Tags: nginx, email, email-server, sendmail

I'm using NGinx on my Webserver. Is it possible to send Emails via the NGinx server, without an account (gmail, microsoft,...) and without a dedicated SMTP server on the server?

The mailtraffic of my domain is handled by an other server.
I just want to send mails from the server (informations, warnings, quotalimits,...) to some people.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, you need an email server. Gmail, Office 365, Zoho, Fastmail, etc are hosted email servers, which is far easier than running your own server. AuthSMTP is a sending only service which is simpler, cheap, and reliable.

You can use SSMTP to send emails from your server. I have a [tutorial that includes that here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/).